# How can i upload file with Apollo server 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, graphql, apollo-server

I am developing an social media backend application using apolloserver 4, I want to add a functionality to upload image for post. I search all the docs unable to find how can I develop Graphql API in apollo server 4 to upload an image.

I searched about `graphql-Upload` but it is not working and Found no document related

I expect the solution should be latest and in Es6 version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking about how can i add a functionality in my graphapi backend to upload image with react application

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a working example using](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/apollo4-graphql-upload-express-2nnbw4?file=%2Findex.mjs) graphql-upload on Apollo 4 with Express, and an example CURL request here (note that you'll need to update the url with the one shown when you launch the sandbox):

```
$ curl https://2nnbw4-4000.csb.app/ \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($id: String!, $image: Upload!) { uploadImage(id: $id, image: $image) { id filename } }", "variables": { "image": null, "id": "1" } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.image"] }' \
  -F 0=@tmp.jpg \
  -H 'Apollo-Require-Preflight: true'

{"data":{"uploadImage":{"id":"1","filename":"tmp.jpg"}}}
```

There's documentation from the Apollo team on [best practices for image upload here](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/file-uploads/file-upload-best-practices/), and some notes about using graphql-upload with [CSRF protection here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/#graphql-upload). Simply put, to avoid getting blocked by CSRF protection, you need to either

1. Send a `Apollo-Require-Preflight` or `X-Apollo-Operation-Name` header with the request
2. Disable CSRF protection with `new ApolloServer({ csrfPrevention: false })`